# Play Audio/Sound on Web AR (Model-Viewer) on an HTTPS Website?

Tags: augmented-reality, model-viewer

I created a web AR demo (Android Chrome) with a sound file attached. The AR with the sound works on an HTTP website, but not on HTTPS. It seems that HTTPS requires user interaction to do so. I just wonder how Google did this with their AR animals (i.e. search for "Tiger" in Google and use the AR button). Unfortunately, there is no documentation on their website about the audio implementation.

How can I get this working on an HTTPS website?

`<model-viewer src="assets/my3DModel.glb?sound=assets/mySound.ogg"...`

Development Source: https://modelviewer.dev